# How to abort pending jquery ajax request when user navigates to other page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

I have defined a method to send jquery ajax request like this

```
sendAjaxRequest(URL, data) {
    return $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST',
        url         : URL,
        crossDomain : true,
        data        : JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType    : 'json'
    }).fail((responseData) => {
        if (responseData.responseCode) {
            console.error(responseData.responseCode);
        }
    });
}
```

From the place of calling I keep the reference of ajax call

```
this.ajaxRequest = sendAjaxRequest(Url, data);
```

and based on user navigation if user navigates away from page **( goes to another page on same website via router )** I want to cancel any pending ajax request.

From the docs I found that jquery `jqXHR` object has an `abort` method to cancel any ajax request. But in my `ajaxRequest` object I don't have any such method available. I am using **jquery 2.2**.

For clarification I also want to add that I am using **react**, and want to achieve this.

```
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.serverRequest = $.get(this.props.source, function (result) {
      var lastGist = result[0];
      this.setState({
        username: lastGist.owner.login,
        lastGistUrl: lastGist.html_url
      });
    }.bind(this));
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    this.serverRequest.abort();
  },
```

Taken from this [link](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html).

They basically say that **When fetching data asynchronously, use componentWillUnmount to cancel any outstanding requests before the component is unmounted.**

I must be doing something wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The browser will do this for you automatically. Note that the request will still be sent and processed by the server. All `abort()` does is stop the browser listening for the response.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan _"The browser will do this for you automatically."_ Was not aware that navigating to a different tab automatically aborted ajax request on previous tab

Comment: @guest271314 it doesn't work when you change the active browser tab - only when the page is unloaded.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'm guessing this is a miscommunication. OP do you mean navigate away using React Router or to a completely different page on the internet?

Comment: Not completely different page(not any other website), on the same website but different page.

Comment: How is the other page being served? I ask because `componentWillUnmount` will never even run if you're getting a new HTML page... this *isn't* React Router or some kind of history api thing?

Comment: it is a different react component you can visualize as tabs each pointing to different different react component. When clicked on a tab component associated with that tab gets rendered, which may also perform some data fetch via ajax call. I want that if user clicks on a tab which sends ajax request to load data( may be thousands of records ) but immediately clicks on another tab, just cancel the previous ajax request.

Comment: `crossDomain : true,` why is that there? it is only useful for making same-origin jsonp requests.

Comment: So are you settingState with the new page information? Dispatching an action? What does clicking a new tab actually do? Is it a `<Link>` component?

Comment: @KevinB Yes I am making cross origin request. Should it not be there in that case?

Comment: You're setting the property value to it's default value, in other words, it is pointless to set it. Its default value is `true` when the request is a cross-origin request. Most of the answers suggesting it are mis-informed..

Comment: Can you list a few of the properties that *are* available on `this.serverRequest`?

Comment: It has only functions available such as success, done, complete, fail, then etc @KevinB

Comment: Sounds an awful lot like a jsonp request, which doesn't make sense given the code you provided. Do you see the request in the network tab under xhr? What about under scripts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jqXHR), you're doing it properly. The `$.ajax()` function returns an object that has an `abort` function. You should check for existence of the function because it might not exist if the request has already finished.

```
componentWillUnmount: function(){
  if (this.ajaxRequest && this.ajaxRequest.abort){
    this.ajaxRequest.abort()
  }
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jqXHR

Comment: I've written a lot of code with jQuery and never ever ever ran into a `jqXHR` object that did not have an `abort()` method or that had it and then lost it. I've also read the code of jQuery to emulate what it does with `jqXHR` and did not see any place where it removes `abort()` after the query is finished. Can you produce a case that illustrates this behavior or point to the lines of code where jQuery removes `abort()`?

Comment: jquery will never remove the abort function, but I don't think its safe to guarantee that `this.ajaxRequest` will always be a `jqXHR` object and never `null` or `undefined`

Answer (score 2):

Please don't try to abort the AJAX request in this case. The better way is **not to do anything if the component is unmounted**. Take a look at this:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  // Register to the handler
  this._requestSuccess = this.requestSuccess.bind(this); 
  $.get(this.props.source, this.requestSuccess);
},

componentWillUnmount: function() {
  // "Unregister" by assign it to an empty function
  this._requestSuccess = () => {};
 },

requestSuccess(lastGist) {
  // Do your work
  this.setState({
    username: lastGist.owner.login,
    lastGistUrl: lastGist.html_url
  });
},
```

In the big picture, not just Ajax requests but any async operation inside a component that may **change the component's states** should be **register** in `componentDidMount` and **unregister** in `componentWillUnmount`, or else you'll find yourself get lost async spaghetti mess.

In the above example, I used `this._requestSuccess = ...;` to register and `this._requestSuccess = () => {};` to unregister the handler, but in real world application, you'll see people use [**Flux**](https://facebook.github.io/flux/) or [**Redux**](https://github.com/reactjs/redux) to do the same thing.

I highly encourage you to use one of those to manage your application data flow rather than just sending and aborting ajax requests everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Just have a look on the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bhatnagar018/x5v3yjeg/). Run the fiddle and check the network tab.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var _ajax = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "yourURL",
    crossDomain: true,
    data: JSON.stringify('hello'),
    dataType: 'json'
  }).fail((responseData) => {
    if (responseData.responseCode) {
      console.error(responseData.responseCode);
    }
  });
  _ajax.abort();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>
  Click me
</button>
```

The ajax variable will hold all the ajax related functions as shown in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

If `componentWillUnmount` is not called have a look at your router configuration.

```jsx
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
  <Route path="invoices/:invoiceId" component={Invoice}/>
  <Route path="accounts/:accountId" component={Account}/>
</Route>
```

In this example the `{App}` component is never unmounted since it's at the root. When you navigate from `/invoices/` to `/invoices/123` the Invoices component is not unmounted either.

Alternatively you can also tie in to the routers `setRouteLeaveHook` like this

```js
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

const MyComponent = React.creatClass({

  componentDidMount() {
    this.request = $.get( /* ... */ );

    this.props.router.setRouteLeaveHook(this.props.route, (request) => {
      request.abort();
      return true;
    });
  }

/* .... */

});


export default withRouter(MyComponent);
```

`withRoute` became available in react-router 2.4.0